# RHEL 6.4 and OpenSSL 1.0.1 - Dependency missing.. but it isn't?

Tags: yum, openssl

I am trying to install phpMyAdmin, however I am getting an error about openssl libraries being missing. However, I have installed them using the ius repo;

```
Error: Package: php-cli-5.4.26-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-5.4.26-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-recode-5.4.26-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: librecode.so.0()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Version check for openssl;

```
[root@fts003lhr yum.repos.d]# openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
built on: Wed Oct 16 16:35:53 EDT 2013
platform: linux-x86_64
options:  bn(64,64) md2(int) rc4(8x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) idea(int) blowfish(idx)
compiler: gcc -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DKRB5_MIT -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -Wall -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -Wa,--noexecstack -DPURIFY -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/etc/pki/tls"
engines:  rsax dynamic
```

I'm on RHEL 6.4 Santiago.

EDIT:
After running `whatprovides`

```
[root@fts003lhr yum.repos.d]# yum whatprovides */libcrypto.so.10
Loaded plugins: product-id, replace, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
openssl-1.0.0-20.el6_2.5.i686 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-4.el6.i686 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-20.el6_2.1.i686 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-20.el6_2.2.i686 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-20.el6_2.2.x86_64 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.i686 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-20.el6_2.4.x86_64 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-10.el6_1.5.x86_64 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-10.el6_1.5.i686 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-10.el6_1.4.x86_64 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-25.el6_3.1.x86_64 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-4.el6.x86_64 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-25.el6_3.1.i686 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-4.el6_0.1.i686 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-10.el6.i686 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-4.el6_0.2.x86_64 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-4.el6_0.2.i686 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-20.el6_2.4.i686 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-10.el6.x86_64 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-20.el6.i686 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-20.el6.x86_64 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-4.el6_0.1.x86_64 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-20.el6_2.5.x86_64 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.x86_64 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-20.el6_2.1.x86_64 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-10.el6_1.4.i686 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-27.el6.i686 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-20.el6_2.3.x86_64 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-20.el6_2.3.i686 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10



openssl-1.0.0-27.el6.x86_64 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-6-6.4.1
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10



openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-2.ius.el6.x86_64 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : installed
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10
```

Answer (score 6):

Just because you have the actual libraries installed doesn't mean the dependency has been satisfied. That's one of the problems with so many different repositories being around - there are times when dependencies between the repos are difficult if not impossible to correct. To start, in your case, I would do a `yum whatprovides */libcrypto.so.10`, then see if that package is installed. It probably isn't, according to the RPM database. Did you install that package via a `./configure; make; make install`? If so, doing a simple `yum install` against what the `yum whatprovides` returned should resolve this issue for you.

Comment: I installed the package using the `yum install openssl10` from the `ius` repo. I have just run the `whatprovides` command you suggested. Unfortunately it didn't fix the problem. I've updated my question with the output.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the IUS package doesn't provide the correct `provide` in this case. It provides the correct library, but that's not the same as far as RPM is concerned. The command I gave specifically asks about the library file, not the actual provide. The ebst I can suggest is to try to find the `openssl` package from the remi repo and replace the IUS package with it, or use the base RHEL repo for all your `openssl` and `php-*` packages.

Answer (score 4):

Often such results are due to repository hickups (packages got uploaded/deleted while building the indices, perhaps?), wrong or missing dependencies, or local dizziness. The former usually get cleared up in a few hours (or a day); the later can be corrected by cleaning the messed up local copy of the repository metadata (`yum clean metadata`) and trying again.

Sometimes cruft from earlier installation (attempts) or failed uninstallations stays around and interferes. Run a `package-cleanup --cleandupes`, and check the program's manual page for other options.

*Don't* use third party repositories (except for EPEL or SC). If you do, factor the cost of handling possible discrepancies, extraofficial packages overriding distribution-provides ones, and assorted other problems.

**Don't ever, under penalty of excomulgation** install software directly from source. Your package management system won't know about it, and you definitely will end up in a horrible tangle. No, the question is not "if," it is "when." Learn how to build your own packages if there is a dire need, but consider that to the extra costs mentioned in the above point you are now responsible for configuring to integrate with the distribution, troubleshooting, tracking upstream versions, hot-fixes, and sometimes backporting patches from the latest git (or other VCS).

Answer (score 0):

1. download the rpm from [this link](ftp://ftp.muug.mb.ca/mirror/centos/6.5/updates/x86_64/Packages/openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.14.x86_64.rpm)
2. `rpm -Uvh openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.14.x86_64.rpm`
3. `rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm`
4. `yum install php54w`

Answer (score 0):

Try installing openssl and openssl-libs simultaneously with the following command for RHEL7 or CentOS 7 (Adjust the package as per your OS variant) :

```
sudo yum install http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/openssl-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64.rpm http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/openssl-libs-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

As both openssl and openssl-libs requires each other as dependecies and running without sudo can arise conflict issues with older version.