# RHEL 6.4: Openssl 1.0.0-27 libcrypto and libssl missing

Tags: rhel, openssl

I am trying to install `znc` IRC bouncer, which needs openssl libraries:

```
Error: Package: znc-1.4-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: znc-1.4-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
```

`yum whatprovides */lib64/libcrypto.so.10`:

```
openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.x86_64 : A general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
Repo        : installed
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

`ldconfig -v egrep -i "libssl\.so|libcrypto\.so"`:

```
ldconfig: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/kernel-2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64.conf:6: duplicate hwcap 1 nosegneg
    libssl.so.10 -> libssl.so.1.0.0
    libcrypto.so.10 -> libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

`yum list openssl`:

```
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
*Note* Red Hat Network repositories are not listed below. You must run this command as root to access RHN repositories.
Installed Packages
openssl.x86_64                                                         1.0.0-27.el6_4.2                                                         @release-rhel-x86_64-workstation-6-r
```

What am I missing?

The package that provides required libraries is installed and libraries are searchable from rpm/yum.

Any pointers? I believe similar question was asked in [RHEL 6.4 and OpenSSL 1.0.1 - Dependency missing.. but it isn't?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119315/rehl-6-4-and-openssl-1-0-1-dependency-missing-but-it-isnt) but that seems to be 32bit vs 64bit issue.

Answer (score 4):

A simple re-install openssl will do!
You can use yum to re-install:

```
yum reinstall openssl
```

or download the rpm file and use the following to install it:

```
 rpm -ivh --force
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem trying to install `postgresql94` (from PostgreSQL repo for RHEL 6) on a 6.4 system without upgrades. The only way to fix my problem was to download and install 6.7 `RPM`s with `openssl` 1.0.1 series.

PS. I have no yum at all on this machine, so I did it manually.